# Can Onelogin generate a Google authentication and refresh tokens with proper scopes?

Tags: api, onelogin

I have an application that currently allows users to authenticate with their Google account. In addition to authenticating the user, the application asks for various calendar specific scopes so that the application can communicate with the user's Google calendar.

I am exploring Onelogin SSO due to the requests of some users. But I assume that Onelogin cannot generate a Google token for our application to assume. Am I correct in that assumption and, if so, what is the "correct" user flow here? Onelogin -> our app -> Google Oauth --> our app?